# How may I find out how to bring a terminal up?

Tags: 12.04

I am a brand new user of Ubuntu and cannot figure out how to get to a terminal. What do I need to know?

Answer (score 1):

Hit Ctrl + Alt + T to open the terminal.  Or you can go to the Ubuntu Menu and search "Terminal". Hope that helped!  :)